# Update column of certain row and return its id

Tags: oracle, locking

I need an idea from you to solve my little problem here. I've got a table which consists of some jobs with an ID, a TIMESTAMP, a STATE and some other values defining what the job actually is. I need to find the ID with the lowest TIMESTAMP and where STATE = 1 and the STATE has to be set to 2 in the same atomic operation.

This would be the way to do it if there is really only one client connected to the database:
First select the ID with the lowest TIMESTAMP.

```
SELECT * FROM SW_ASYNC_JOBS WHERE STATE = 1 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

We store the ID into a variable, say JOB_ID, then set its STATE to 2:

```
UPDATE SW_ASYNC_JOBS SET STATE = 2 WHERE JOB_ID = :JOB_ID
```

Now the client has all the data it needs, set the state to "in progress" and starts working on the job.

Of course in reality between these two operations there will be an other client which does the same and a race condition will definitely occur. Both clients may work on the same job which is fatal.

I was searching around the web and found the SELECT FOR UPDATE and WHERE CURRENT OF statements but it seems there is no way to also retrieve all the columns of the job. I started with something like this:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR FRESH_JOB IS
        SELECT * FROM SW_ASYNC_JOBS WHERE STATE = 1 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
    FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
    FOR JOB IN FRESH_JOB LOOP
        UPDATE SW_ASYNC_JOBS SET STATE = 2 WHERE CURRENT OF FRESH_JOB;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But somehow I get the error `ORA-02014: cannot select FOR UPDATE from view` which is weird because the table SW_ASYNC_JOBS is a simple table with a primary key over two columns.

What would be the best way to solve that problem? Should I lock the whole table to get the oldest job and change its state?

For completeness this is the table I am talking about:

```
CREATE TABLE SW_ASYNC_JOBS (
    "MASTER_JOB_ID" NUMBER(22, 0) NOT NULL,
    "JOB_ID" NUMBER(22, 0) NOT NULL,
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    "UID" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    "VIEW" VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL,
    "JSON" VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
    "TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "STATE" NUMBER(2, 0) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "SW_ASYNC_PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY ("MASTER_JOB_ID", "JOB_ID")
)
```

There are other clients that retrieve fresh sequence numbers from one sequence to add new rows to that table. First a MASTER_JOB_ID is retrieved, then for every "slave job" there is another fresh sequence number used. So in principle no number within `MASTER_JOB_ID` and `JOB_ID` can be occur twice. The `MASTER_JOB_ID` is only there to combine several "slave jobs" and to show their status group wise.

The client is a Python script which uses the `cx_Oracle` package in version 12.1.0.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the question, but - why separating `SELECT` and `UPDATE`? Wouldn't such a statement do the job? `RETURNING` clause is used to return the JOB_ID.

```
declare
  retval sw_async_jobs.job_id%type;
begin
  update sw_async_jobs s set
    s.state = 2
    where s.job_id = (select s1.job_id
                      from sw_async_jobs s1
                      where s1.state = 1
                      order by s1.timestamp fetch first 1 row only
                     )
  returning job_id into retval;

  dbms_output.put_line('retval = ' || retval);
end;
/
```

Comment: I also need the ID of the job which state was changed.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, forgot that. How about the RETURNING clause? I've modified my message. Have a look, please.

Comment: This dbms_output seems not to work properly with cx_Oracle. I do not see any retval anywhere.

Comment: I used it just to ... well, *do something* with RETVAL. You don't have to use it, of course.

Comment: I don't get it to run with cx_Oracle and Python. It runs somehow and does its thing but I see no return value when running your code with DBeaver. And with `cx_Oracle.execute()` I get ORA-06550 and PLS-00103 errors because it founds the symbol "end-of-file" but expects ";". I get the errors in German, this was a vague translation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know cx_Oracle nor Python so - no idea what might be wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found an other maybe unconventional solution for this.

```
def getNextJobId(self) :
    """ Return Id of the oldest job which is in 'ready' state
    """

    # Lock the table
    cursor = self._execute("LOCK TABLE %s IN EXCLUSIVE MODE" % self._jobTableName)

    try :
        jobId = None

        while jobId is None :

            # Find potential job Id in 'ready' state
            cursor = self._execute("SELECT JOB_ID FROM %s WHERE STATE = :READY_STATE ORDER BY TIMESTAMP, JOB_ID FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY" % self._jobTableName,
                                   {'READY_STATE' : JobStates.ready.value})

            rows = list(cursor)

            # Is there is no such job, quit
            if len(rows) == 0 :
                self._rollback()
                break

            # If there is a potential job, save its Id
            elif len(rows) >= 1 :
                # 'rows' has this form: [(int,)]
                potentialJobId = rows[0][0]

            # Now we change its state. In the WHERE clause we also check if the job still is in 'ready' state.
            statement = "UPDATE %s SET STATE = :WORKING_STATE WHERE JOB_ID = :JOB_ID AND STATE = :READY_STATE" % self._jobTableName

            cursor = self._execute(statement, {'READY_STATE' : JobStates.ready.value,
                                               'WORKING_STATE' : JobStates.working.value,
                                               'JOB_ID' : potentialJobId})

            # If there was exactly one row changed, we now have the job
            if cursor.rowcount == 1 :
                jobId = potentialJobId
                self._commit()

            # If nothing was changed through the UPDATE, another client got the same potential job and changed the state already. Try again.

        return jobId

    finally :
        self._rollback()
```

Because the table is locked and `UPDATE` is atomic it should work without problems now. At first I was interested in avoiding the loop but when I was talking to a guy in `#oracle-database` on Freenode it looks like there would be race conditions when trying it an other way and without a loop.

I don't want to mark this solution as solution to the question. Maybe someone else has a better idea to do this with Python and cx_Oracle.